# Emacs - bind keys after a module is loaded

Tags: node.js, emacs

I would like to set up a Node.js keybindings REPL for emacs. I had a look at [`nodejs-repl`](https://github.com/abicky/nodejs-repl.el), and I can now open a REPL and use the [`nodejs-send-region`](https://github.com/abicky/nodejs-repl.el/blob/develop/nodejs-repl.el#L283) command to execute code.

However I cannot figure out how to bind for instance `C-c C-e` to this command. I think that I have to use the `comint-mode` for that (?) . I tried:

```el
(require 'nodejs-repl)

;; bind shortcuts when in node mode-line
(eval-after-load 'nodejs-repl
  (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-e") #'nodejs-repl-send-region)))
```

Comment: Note that `eval-after-load` takes a quoted form for evaluation. `lambda` is self-quoting, so that's not an *error*, but evaluating a lambda merely defines a function -- it doesn't execute it, so the body of that function is never evaluated. You wanted `(eval-after-load 'nodejs-repl '(define-key ...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding the key in the keymap that is currently local after the library is loaded. Loading the library most likely does **not** turn on the mode whose keymap you really want to bind the key in. At least that's typical, and it corresponds to [GNU Emacs coding conventions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html), which say:

> Simply loading a package should not change Emacs’s editing
>        behavior.  Include a command or commands to enable and disable the
>        feature, or to invoke it.
>
> This convention is mandatory for any file that includes custom
>        definitions.  If fixing such a file to follow this convention
>        requires an incompatible change, go ahead and make the incompatible
>        change; don’t postpone it.

What you want to do instead is to bind the key in the proper keymap, using `define-key`, and you want to do that in the mode hook.

```el
(require 'nodejs-repl)
(define-key nodejs-repl-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-e") #'nodejs-repl-send-region)
```